# Find the markers position in google map while moving camera positions

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, android-maps

How to find the markers and markers positions `(Lat,Lan)` on Google map while moving the camera position.?

Comment: To create a marker, you must set its position, so you already have this information, don't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using oncamera change listener you can get latitude and longitude

```
map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
            LatLng latvalue = position.target;
            double lat = latvalue.latitude;
            double lng = latvalue.longitude;
        }
    });
```